# Express middleware applied to all methods instead of to these defined in controller

Tags: javascript, express, cors

I defined controller which has only one function and this function is set as a callback to `GET /user/ request:

```
class UserController {
  async getAllUserData(req, res) { /* get data, return res */ }
  async changepassword(req, res) { /* change password, return res */ }
}

const ctrl = new UserController();

api.get('/user', middlewareA, ctrl.getAllUserData);
api.post('/changepassword', ctrl.changepassword);

export default api;
```

This works fine, middleware is applied only to `GET /user` route. However, I wanted to specify middleware to all functions defined in single controller file and apply this middleware on the level of my `index.js` file, like this:

```
/* initialization... */

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Token');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  next();
});

app.use(middleware, UserController);

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

However, in the second snippet, as I put middleware before UserController, this middleware is applied to all methods - especially to `OPTIONS` request which is sent by browser - even thought `UserController` has only 2 methods which have `GET` and `POST` methods.

Why the middleware in the second snippet is applied to all methods? Do I have to put it separately to every function in every controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In express, everything that you chain with `app.use()` is called in order. This is what will happen in your second snippet:

1. Request starts
2. Runs header middleware
3. Runs your 'middleware' (the one included before `UserController`)
4. Runs `UserController`
5. Runs routes middleware
6. Return response

The main thing to note is that middleware and route middleware are the same thing and they will happen in whichever order you are `app.use()`'ing them.

You can either assign the middleware like you did in your first snippet, or check the URL in the middleware. Another option would be to group your URL's.

```
app.use('/example', middleware);
app.use('/example', UserController);

// ........
api.get('/example/user', middlewareA, ctrl.getAllUserData);
api.post('/example/changepassword', ctrl.changepassword);
```

There are plenty of examples in the [express documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.application).